# how to convert the values from a json array to a java string

Tags: java, arrays, json

I need to take the values from a JSON array and display them. Below is the code I have used.

`getresponse` class will send a HTTP request to a PHP page and get the relevant JSON array and the public variable **res** will hold that returned JSON array.

```
public class JSONConverter {
     public void convert(){
        getresponse gr=new getresponse();
        String json = gr.res;
        Data data = new Gson().fromJson(json, Data.class);
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}

class Data {
    private String city;
    private int reserve_no;

    public String getCity() { return city; }
    public int getReserve_no() { return reserve_no; }

    public void setTitle(String city) { this.city = city; }
    public void setId(int reserve_no) { this.reserve_no = reserve_no; }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format(city);
    } 
}
```

**getrespose class**

```
public class getresponse {
public static String res;
  public void counter() {
 try {
    URL url = new URL("http://taxi.net/fetchLatest.php");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        (conn.getInputStream())));
            String str;
    while ((str =br.readLine()) != null) {                                  
                    res=str;

    }

    conn.disconnect();
```

Below is an example of JSON array returned.

> [{"reserve_no":"20","city":"city2","street":"street1234","discription":"discription123","date":"2012-10-22
>   04:47:54","customer":"abc"}]

This code doesn't display the city name of the JSON array returned. can someone help me with this by correcting the code or suggest a better or easier method if any? :)

Comment: There is absolutely no correlation between your Data class and the returned JSON, so how would GSON know what it should do?  You should probably create a more appropriate Data class, with fields matching the names of the fields in the JSON string.

Comment: yeah i  did those changes! title as city and id as reserve_no but im not still getting the relevent city name from the response

Comment: So you're saying the posted code sample doesn't really have a relation (anymore) with what you're actually running?  That makes it a bit difficult for us to spot problems, don't you think so?  You should update your code sample in the question in that case.

Comment: i have updated it! please check :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nikita already gave you the correct solution, but here it is, step by step.

I reduced your problem to this minimal test:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class TestGSON 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        // that's your JSON sample
        String json = "[{\"reserve_no\":\"20\",\"city\":\"city2\",\"street\":\"street1234\",\"discription\":\"discription123\",\"date\":\"2012-10-22 04:47:54\",\"customer\":\"abc\"}]";
        // note: we tell Gson to expect an **array** of Data
        Data data[] = new Gson().fromJson(json, Data[].class);
        System.out.println(data[0]);
    }
}
```

The problem is that your JSON fragment is actually an **array** of objects, not just an object (hence the [] around it).  So, you need to tell GSon it must expect an array of Data, not just a Data object.  By the way, the exception that's thrown when executing your code as-is already told you so:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2
```

unless of course it got swallowed by an empty `catch` block

With respect to the Data class: think twice before you override the toString method like you did here.  I would drop that method and just do

```
System.out.println( data[0].getCity() );
```

Answer (score 2):

Gson maps json string to your class basing on your class properties names. So `Data` class has property `title` which is supposed to be mapped to `city` in json array. You need to rename you property to `city` so Gson can figure out where to put `city` from json array.
Or you can use annotations to explicitly map `city` to `title`. Check this: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-JSON-Field-Naming-Support

Comment: thank you for your quick reply! even after i have changed them im not getting the city name from the response recieved. anything else i should do to the coding?

Comment: On more problem. You have and ARRAY of json object. And you want to convert it to single object. You can't. Try something like `Data[] datas = new Gson().fromJson(json, Data[].class);`

Comment: i want to get few specific values only. as in the example response i want to get only the city2 and 20 values. is there anyway i can do it?